# Is it ok to use $out for temporary collections?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I tried to create single aggregation request but without any luck - I need to split it. I think I can do following:

1. First aggregation request will filter/transform/sort/limit documents
   and save result to temporary collection by using `$out`
2. After that, I'll execute 2-3 aggregation requests on temporary
   collection
3. Finally, I'll delete temporary collection

By saving data to a temporary collection, I'll skip filter/sort/limit stages on subsequent aggregation requests.

Is it ok? What's the overhead of this approach? What's the main usage of `$out` operator?

Comment: A common usage of the `$out` operator is to allow working with aggregation results larger than the maximum size of a BSON document (inline results are limited to 16MB as at MongoDB 3.0). Using `$out` to create interim/temporary collections is also a reasonable use case. If you haven't posted a question on your aggregation pipeline already, it would probably be worth doing so to see if there might be a more concise or efficient way to achieve the same outcome in less than 3-4 aggregation passes. I think that many passes suggests the extra calculation may even be better done in client code ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Yes; MongoDB does this itself when it runs map-reduce aggregations: [Temporary Collection in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727687/temporary-collection-in-mongodb)

It would be great to get specifics as to what you are trying to accomplish as it may be possible to do in a single aggregation or map-reduce operation.